# Preview in Lion fails when any document opened has changed

Tags: macos, software, preview

In Lion Preview.app, if I have many image files open in a single preview window (so that I can scroll through them) and one of them changes on disk (e.g., I remade the image with a plotting program or `convert`), instead of loading the new image, the whole preview window shows an empty background for all images, even those that have not changed.

In Snow Leopard and Leopard, preview would just reload the new image in place.

Is there any way to fix the Lion version of Preview?

EDIT: related post [refresh Preview from command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3650/refresh-preview-from-command-line)

Comment: Probably no wat to fix it, but you can submit bug report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather unsatisfactory solution might be `File->Open Recent->*top of the list*`

I suggest *unsatisfactory* because

- it launches a new window
- you have to go and close the old window
- the folder you are in might not be at the top of the list
- it's not a keyboard shortcut
- it's not automatic
- it requires a lot of mousing and a couple of clicks
- it makes me have to think

but i digress with this bitching and moaning, did anyone post an issue with Apple or find the proper solution?

Comment: +1 for the bitterness; not gonna accept it because it aint a solution